# Solve the Recurrence Relation of $A_{n+1} = A_n+A_{n-1}$ for $n\geq2$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

I am trying to solve some recurrences for an exam that I found from a past final:

I am given $A_1=1$ and $A_2=3$.

I re-wrote the relation as $A_{n+1} - A_n - A_{n-1} =0$ and found the characteristic polynomial, $x^2-x-x=0$

I solve for x and get $x=0, 2$ from $x(x-2)$

$\longrightarrow$ Solving for A and B from $X_n = A(0^n)+B(2^b)$

I first set $n=0$ and get $0=0+B(2^0) \longrightarrow B=0$

I then set $n=1$ and get $1=0+B(2^1) \longrightarrow 2B=1$

So $B=0$ and $B=1/2$

I am not sure where to go from here, or if I made a mistake since I have $ 2$ different values for $B$.

Some help would be much appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: do you know about z-transform ?

Comment: no, I have never heard of it

Answer (score 1):

The characteristic polynomial of the recursion $$A_{n+2} - A_{n+1} - A_n = 0$$

is

$$x^2 - x - 1 $$

This should fix your problems.

Comment: Why is $x^2-x-1$ and no $x^2-x-x$?

Comment: See this link for a definition of a [characteristic polynomial](http://mathcircle.berkeley.edu/BMC3/Bjorn1/node4.html)

Comment: Okay that makes sense.  Thanks.
I do that and then I get $x=\frac{1}{2}(1+\sqrt(5)$ and $x=\frac{1}{2}(1-\sqrt(5))$
I then have $X_n=A(\frac{1}{2}(1+\sqrt(5) + B(\frac{1}{2}(1-\sqrt(5)$.  

Should I solve this by setting n=0 and n=1?
When I do this I have A=-B and then when I plug this into the second equation (when n=1), everything cancels out.   I am not sure if I did something wrong but this is is not making much sense to me..

Comment: I think you're missing a few $n^{\text{th}}$ powers in your formula for $X_n$. The derivation of a closed form from a recursive form is exactly the technique used to show [Binet's formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number#Closed-form_expression). Your sequence is numbers is only different from Fibonacci numbers because your initial terms are different - the recursion is the same.

Comment: Should be $$X_n = X_1 \frac{\left(\frac{1}{2}\left(1+\sqrt{5}\right)\right)^n - \left(-\frac{1}{2}\left(1+\sqrt{5}\right)\right)^{-n}}{\sqrt{5}} + X_0 \frac{\left(\frac{1}{2}\left(1+\sqrt{5}\right)\right)^{n-1} - \left(-\frac{1}{2}\left(1+\sqrt{5}\right)\right)^{1-n}}{\sqrt{5}}$$

See [this link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalizations_of_Fibonacci_numbers#Fibonacci_integer_sequences) for more on this method.